# accessing raspberry pi camera from raspberry pi 3 with android os

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, android

I successfully installed Android 7.1.1 using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xoqi-01FliI) tutorial. But I couldn't find default camera app inside it. Also, I pluged raspberry pi camera (B) rev2.0 on it and installed my own android app but couldn't run it (Error: can't open camera).

I couldn't find anything valuable related this on the internet. Is there a way to access camera? Should I install something else?

Note: This is first time I'm playing with Raspberry.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Note that Android is an experimental build for the Pi so unfortunately resources are rare and users that can report on it aren't plentiful either. By "should I install something else" I assume you're not referring to the installation of a, lets say, more established OS for the Pi?

Comment: Hello, yes, I mean is there any app or something else that can help me access camera . I have an android camera app and I want to test its performance on raspberry pi 3